# Icon themes does not apply to GNOME launcher

Tags: 18.04, icons, themes, gnome-shell, numix

I installed **Arc Dark** with the **Numix** icon set but the icons do not change in the launcher on the left, nor they change in the '*Show Applications*' view. I installed everything via the GNOME Tweak Tool:

[image]

Any idea why?

Comment: how did you install arc dark.. and numix.. manually or..

Comment: For the icons, I followed the instructions here: https://itsfoss.com/best-icon-themes-ubuntu-16-04/

Comment: For Arc, if I remember correctly, I just did `sudo apt install arc-theme`.

Comment: ok.. can you share a pic like this.. when you open gnome-tweaks.. https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3WN7.png

Comment: Sure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3Hdz.png

Comment: Ok.. let me go through this..

Comment: Did you restart your system or relogin once after changing the icon theme?

Comment: I did, multiple times. @pomsky

Comment: @EdgarDerby did not you try numix-circle icon theme from the drop down list?

Comment: Oh my, that was it, @PRATAP. Numix-circle does work... I feel like an idiot. Could you post this as an answer so I can mark it as accepted, please?

Answer (score 0):

when you install the Icon theme in this way

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:numix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install numix-icon-theme-circle
```

select `Numix-Circle` Icon theme..

[image]